# Decimal to any base convertion code in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ programming. I'm writing a program that reads two integers such that one is the decimal number `N` and the other is the base system `b` which I would like to convert to. For base 16, `A` denotes 10, `B` denotes 11 and so on.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
string dec2b();
int N, b;
int rem =0;
int main(){
    cout<<"please input a decimal positive number: "; cin>>N;
    cout<<"please input the desired base: "; cin>>b;
    string s = dec2b();
    cout<<'"'<<N<<'"'<<" in base-10 system = \""<<s<<"\" in base-"<<b<<"system"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

string dec2b()
{
    string s = ""; 
        while(N>0)
        {

            if (b==16)
            {
                rem = N%b;
                if (rem>9)
                {
                    switch (rem)
                    {
                        case 10: s= "A" + s; break;
                        case 11: s= "B" + s; break;
                        case 12: s= "C" + s; break;
                        case 13: s= "D" + s; break;
                        case 14: s= "E" + s; break;
                        case 15: s= "F" + s; break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    s = char(rem+48) +s;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                rem = N%b;
                s = char(rem+48) +s;
            }
        N = N/b;
        }
    if (s=="")
    {cout<<"0";}
    else 
    {cout<<s; }

    return s;
}
```

It works well, but why do I get this error instead of the original value of the integer N?
[image: error]

Comment: Just copy and paste the console output into the question. Don't faff about with images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `N` and `b` local in `main()` function, and change function `string dec2b()` to `string dec2b(int N, int b)`. Also move `int rem = 0` to `dec2b` function. Avoid using global variables.

```
string dec2b(int N, int b);

int main() 
{
    int N, b; // <- add here
    cout << "please input a decimal positive number: "; cin >> N;
    cout << "please input the desired base: "; cin >> b;
    string s = dec2b(N, b); // <- change here
    cout << '"' << N << '"' << " in base-10 system = \"" << s.c_str() << "\" in base-" << b << " system" << endl;
    return 0;
}

string dec2b(int N, int b)
{
    int rem = 0;
    // ...
    // your code here
}
```

---

Result for N=14 and b=16 will be:
**"14" in base-10 system = "E" in base-16 system**

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also realized that I shouldn't have written the if (s=="")
 {cout<<"0";}
 else 
 {cout<<s; }

Comment: can you please explain why avoid using global variables in this code?

Comment: In this case you changed `N` value in `dec2b` function and lost it in `main()`

Comment: @AhmadObeidat avoid global variables at all times, except for some very limited cases. Remember: global variables are evil variables.

Comment: @AhmadObeidat for code that is so short like this, using global variable might not matter that much, although it is true that you have already altered `N` by accident in your code. Similarly, when you are doing even large codes, you are more likely to accidently alter or redefine some global variable.

Answer (score 0):

The number to be converted is passed as a string to the function and base is the base in which number is to be converted.

**C++ Program to convert decimal to any given base**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
// To return char for a value. For example '2' 
// is returned for 2. 'A' is returned for 10. 'B' 
// for 11 
char reVal(int num) 
{ 
if (num >= 0 && num <= 9) 
    return (char)(num + '0'); 
else
    return (char)(num - 10 + 'A'); 
} 

// Utility function to reverse a string 
void strev(char *str) 
{ 
int len = strlen(str); 
int i; 
for (i = 0; i < len/2; i++) 
{ 
    char temp = str[i]; 
    str[i] = str[len-i-1]; 
    str[len-i-1] = temp; 
} 
} 

// Function to convert a given decimal number 
// to a base 'base' and 
char* fromDeci(char res[], int base, int inputNum) 
{ 
int index = 0; // Initialize index of result 

// Convert input number is given base by repeatedly 
// dividing it by base and taking remainder 
while (inputNum > 0) 
{ 
    res[index++] = reVal(inputNum % base); 
    inputNum /= base; 
} 
res[index] = '\0'; 

// Reverse the result 
strev(res); 

return res; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
int inputNum = 282, base = 16; 
char res[100]; 
printf("Equivalent of %d in base %d is "
    " %s\n", inputNum, base, fromDeci(res, base, inputNum)); 
return 0; 
}
```

output: Equivalent of 282 in base 16 is  11A